# Strange incomplete type is not allowed error

Tags: c++

Consider the following code

```
struct dummy1 {
    int b;
    dummy1();
};
struct dummy {

    dummy1 a[];
    int c;
    dummy();

};
int main()
{
    dummy foo;
    foo.a[0].b = 5;
    foo.a[1].b = 6;
    return 0;
}
dummy::dummy()
    :a()
    ,c()
{

}
dummy1::dummy1()
    : b()
{

}
```

I am getting an error "Incomplete type is not allowed" , As far as i know we get this error if the structure we are defining the object of is not defined or the header file is not included which is not the case strangely when I define my `int c` before `a[]` the code works so replacing this

```
struct dummy {
    int c;
    dummy1 a[];
    dummy();

};
```

the code works just fine, Any ideas why this might be happening ?

P.S I am using VS2015

Comment: This is a [flexible array member](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flexible_array_member) which is not allowed in C++, so is probably a compiler extension.

Comment: Oh thanks! I didn't know that it seems that this flexible member array should only be the last member of the struct , makes sense.

Comment: @interjay: You're basically right, but a[] would have to be the last member in the struct.

Comment: @AntonF., Yes, that's why OP got the error.

Comment: Ok, I was too late. But I would use separate allocation for a if possible to fit the standard.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`dummy1 a[];` is not valid.  You must define the size of your array.  If you don't know what size array you need in advance, use [`std::vector`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) instead of a raw array:

```
struct dummy {
    std::vector<dummy1> a;
    int c;
};

int main()
{
    dummy foo;
    foo.a.resize(2);
    foo.a[0].b = 5;
    foo.a[1].b = 6;
}
```

---

The reason it compiles when you swap the order of your members is a feature of C called "flexible array members" that some compilers provide as an extension to C++.  This allows you to declare an array-of-unknown-bound as the last member of a struct.  No memory is reserved for that array when you declare an automatic or static variable of that type though.  It's intended to be used with `malloc`:

```
struct dummy {
    int c;
    dummy1 a[];
};

int main() {
    // allocate storage for 5 dummy1 objects in our flexible array
    dummy* foo = malloc(sizeof(dummy) + 5 * sizeof(dummy1));
    foo->a[0].b = 5;
    foo->a[1].b = 6;
    free(foo);
    return 0;
}
```

Note that this **is not** a standard part of C++.  It is a non-standard compiler extension, and does not play well with many C++ features.  Compilers likely provide this extension mostly for compatibility with libraries written in C.

Answer (score 1):

I guess it is the array a with size 0 in dummy. The standard doesn’t allow this.

Try:

```
struct dummy {

   dummy1* a;
   int c;
   dummy();
};
```

Or:

```
struct dummy {

   dummy1 a[1];
   int c;
   dummy();
};
```